# Windows 10 Start Menu Search Indexing Fields (Filename only? Apparently not!)

Tags: windows, windows-10, search, shortcuts, start-menu

So here's a question that I haven't been able to find the answer to anywhere:

What field(s) does Windows 10 use to index files by whenever performing a start menu search?  The obvious answer would be that it's indexing by filename and filename alone, but I'm not entirely so sure.  If it's not clear what I mean, observe the following example below:

As of right now, the ONLY folder that I have Windows 10 indexing on my computer is the `"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"` folder (and all of its contents).  This is because I put shortcuts to all of my programs in there.  But look at this:

[image]

Notice that the shortcut with the filename "Epic Games Launcher.lnk" showed up first, before the shortcut with the filename "Unreal Engine.lnk."  Now,for those who don't know, there is a relationship between the Epic Games Launcher and Unreal Engine (the Epic Games Launcher is what you use to install Unreal Engine), but I still don't understand why it appears in the search first despite not having the word "Unreal" anywhere in its filename.

I noticed that the "description" of the "Epic Games Launcher.lnk" that can be viewed when opening up the properties says "UnrealEngineLauncher," but whenever I type "UnrealE" into the search, nothing shows up at all, so I don't assume that Windows is using this "description" field to index the shortcuts.  So I have no idea what it's really doing.

Does anybody understand this, and, apart from deleting the Epic Games Launcher shortcut, does anybody know how to make Windows 10 index by filename only?  Thanks.

Comment: At a guess, perhaps it's looking at the executable path in the `.lnk` file.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I doubt that can be it; the path in this case is: 


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Epic Games\Launcher\Portal\Binaries\Win32\EpicGamesLauncher.exe" 


 which does not contain the text string "unreal." Further, if I name a shortcut something completely arbitrary and then type that name into the search, it still shows up.  So it must be indexing by something in addition to the filename, but whatever it is still mystifies me.  I suspect it could be a property somewhere that the epic games launcher itself set whenever I installed it, but who knows where that is?

Comment: So, in general, I'm wondering what Windows is actually doing whenever you do these searches.  I really want to find out!

Comment: Can you reproduce [this](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/windows-start-search-results)? (Search "web browser" and get Edge & IE only)

Comment: @guest-vm, yes, I was basically able to reproduce that.  See here:
https://prnt.sc/jb3d8a
Notice that I also got "choose a default web browser" in addition.

Comment: Integrate [Voidtools Everything](https://www.voidtools.com) to [Classic Shell Start Menu](http://www.classicshell.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1588)

Comment: @guest-vm, yes, I do have other browsers installed.  So it would seem that Windows' methods are indeed very arcane.  Maybe I'll just take a look at Classic Shell and Everything and see what I can do with those.

Comment: *"The obvious answer would be that it's indexing by filename and filename alone."*  That probably isn't the obvious answer.  There are some very good [tutorials online](https://www.howtogeek.com/272158/how-to-choose-which-files-windows-search-indexes-on-your-pc/) that show us that at the very least, **Index Properties Only** is the default.  As a result, I am quite certain that includes the description field of the `Epic Games Launcher.lnk` within the properties realm.  If you look at your Index advanced options, you will [see that setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbveN.jpg) for LNK files.

Comment: *"Does anybody understand this, and, apart from deleting the Epic Games Launcher shortcut, does anybody know how to make Windows 10 index by filename only?"*  While we **do** understand this, I'm afraid that you simply can't make Windows 10 index by filename only.  As you might imagine, Microsoft felt that it was better to provide a comprehensive set of information within their search results, rather than a shortage.  As others have stated, there are some prominent third-party search applications that can provide strict "filename only" results, if that's what you truly desire.

Comment: `Oracle VM VirtualBox.lnk` has `VirtualBox Manager` as its description. Search in start menu: "virtualbox"=>"Oracle VM VirtualBox.lnk", "manager"=>"Device/Task Manager", "virtualbox manager"=>"No result". Search in file explorer under `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox`: "manager"/"virtualbox manager"=>"VirtualBox.exe". Conclusion: `.lnk` is not indexed by description. "web browser" is not found in properties of Edge & IE neither, yet in start menu "web browser"=>"Edge/IE".

Comment: @guest-vm perhaps not, but I think that this entire scenario *is* easier to understand than this lengthy discussion would lead us to believe. The bottom line is that you **can't** utilize the built-in Windows index capabilities to search strictly by filename. The native search index is significantly more in-depth than that. While I am confident that there is documentation somewhere within the Microsoft developers' world that provides a thorough explanation of what is included within the `Properties` that the index utilizes, it seems rather trivial to dwell upon it. The OP needs a 3rd-party app

Comment: @Run5k Utilitarianly, it is unwise to dwell on it, yes. But since OP spent a bounty, I try not to sidestep it with workaround but help elucidate his issue (not everyone has Unreal Engine), in hope of attracting abler people to provide a good answer.

Comment: @guest-vm while I agree with your overall philosophy, from my perspective, the bounty is relatively inconsequential. That's why I didn't attempt to write an answer, instead. However, I still wanted to help the OP as much as possible, and that's also why I didn't flag the post as `too broad` even though it contains multiple questions. The ultimate query is as follows: *"Does anybody know how to make Windows 10 index by filename only?"* The genuine answer should be "no," because unfortunately that isn't possible (regardless of the native Windows 10 index methods that piqued their curiosity).

Answer (score -1):

You have two parts to your question.
First, "does anybody understand this."
[According to Microsoft:](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4098843/windows-10-search-indexing-faq)

> "By default, all the properties of your files are indexed, including
>   file names and full file paths. For files with text, their contents
>   are indexed to allow you to search for words within the files."

Of course, this is not as specific as we might like, but it is easy to see how Unreal Engine could be associated with the Epic Games Launcher, since the indexing  is this broad.
This means that the hypothesis "that Windows is using this 'description' field to index the shortcuts" is in fact correct.
Fortunately Windows does allow *some* control over this behavior, even if it is not as much as one might like.

That brings us to the second part of the question:
"Does anybody know how to make Windows 10 index by filename only?"

The short answer to this part of the question is "no."
Windows does allow some modification of indexing behavior, but not in great detail.  On Windows 10 (and some earlier version) in your Indexing Options, in Advanced, you can change indexing behavior on a per-file-extension basis.  Unfortunately, it does not allow fine-grained choices such as "only by filename."  Your two choices are "index properties only" and "index properties and file contents."  In your case even the more restricted "index properties only" option will include the description, because that is part of the file's properties.

There is an additional piece of information relevant to this whole discussion: why does "Epic Games Launcher" not only show up, but show up as the *best* as the Best Match?  Briefly put, "Best Match" is a potentially misleading label.  This is a result field that attempts to find what the user is most likely interested in, not some simple ranking of how closely a result matches the search term.